# How to get contents of a directory without including system/hidden files in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to get the contents of a directory as an array excluding system / hidden files and folders.  `FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)` and `FileSystem.GetFiles(path)`  returns all files included in the path. So how to exclude system/hidden files from it?

Comment: There is no option available directly on these functions to do this. You will likely have to get `FileInfo` about each entry and see if it is a system file or not.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, thought there'll be some better way. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an old question but here the solution!

```
FileSystem.GetFiles(path).Where(Function(file) ((file.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden) AndAlso (file.Attributes And FileAttributes.System) <> FileAttributes.System)
```

I just checked all files against the two flags you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will have to modify the linq query or just use the Directory Info Object Directly

```
Dim root As String = "X:\" 

        'Take a snapshot of the folder contents 
        Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(root)

        Dim fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        ' This query will produce the full path for all .txt files 
        ' under the specified folder including subfolders. 
        ' It orders the list according to the file name. 
        Dim fileQuery = From file In fileList _
                        Where file.Extension = ".txt" and file.Length >1645 _
                        Order By file.Length _
                        Select file
```

Comment: Can you explain? I dont want to list all txt files.