# Copy directory but exclude child folder

Tags: vb.net

My current solution is that I can copy over a folder to a different directory

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(
"C:\Users\myname\path1\path2",
"C:\Users\myname\path1\path2\path3",
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

What I'm looking to do is to copy the `path2` directory and all it's files (which it currently does) but exclude one of the child folders within `path2` which is called `data`

How will I go about doing this? [This forum post does something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342062/how-to-get-contents-of-a-directory-without-including-system-hidden-files-in-vb-n) but uses `getFile` to exclude hidden files

Answer (score 0):

You should think about how would you do it by hand. You don't copy the main folder. You open it and select all that you need. Similarly we do that with code. First of all we add all folders and the files of the main folder to an array.

```
            'copy all folders, exclude the data folder
            Dim Paths As New ArrayList
            Paths.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\TestDirectory1"))
            For Each Item As String In Paths
                If Not Item.ToString.Contains("\data\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Item, "C:\TestDirectory2", True)
                End If
            Next
            'copy all files of the main folder
            Dim Files As New ArrayList
            Files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\TestDirectory1"))
            For Each Item As String In Paths
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Item, "C:\TestDirectory2", True)
            Next
```

We don't want the \data\ folder so it will not be added to the ArrayList. I did not had the chance to test the code yet but I hope it brings you on the right track!

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a viable solution and I can understand your theory behind this. Testing your code, an error appears saying "Could not find folder "information"". This is an additional folder that's in "directory1" which I want copying across that's alongside the "data" folder, the one I don't want copying across

Comment: My bad, I didn't state the 2nd directory in the first instance. I have a new problem though, using your solution, it copies the files within the folders in 'TestDirectory1' and places them into 'TestDirectory2' without excluding the 'data' folder OR copying the root files in 'TestDirectory1'